# xubuntu 18.04 open/save file dialog, sorting

Tags: xubuntu

I am usung Xubuntu 18.04. There is an annoying problem.

When I open or save a file sorting in that dialog is wierd: it is sorted by name no matter files or directories. Directories are not listed first.

Is it possible to change it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the column header to sort according to that column. That, provided you are looking in a folder. This will not work when Recent files are listed.

To show folders first, change the setting in your file manager's options. If the option is not exposed there, then you still can change it with the command:

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser sort-directories-first true
```

Comment: Clicking on a column doesn't help. It changes only sorting order. I'll check the gsettings.

Comment: That fixed it. It is wierd that it is false by default.

Comment: Column sorting and the option "directories first" are two different things indeed.